# How can I make this if-condition simpler?

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, switch-statement, logic

I'm trying to make a simple if-condition. Unfortunately, I have the same condition twice in it (and I'd like to avoid it).

I'm building a flow on this site: http://code2flow.com/#

The code looks like this:

```
Prerequisite for certification and exam;
if(test 1 >= 15 points)
{
  certification 1;
  exam 1;
  if(test 2 >= 15 point)
  {
    certification 2;
    exam 1 + 2;
  }
}
else if(test 2 >= 15 point)
{
  certification 2;
}
```

Explained: A person has to pass a test in a course (there are 2 courses). He has to achieve at least 15 points to get a certification for the course.

If the person has at least 15 points in test 1, he gets a certification for course 1 and is allowed to write the exam for course 1.

If the person has at least 15 points in test 2, he gets a certification for course 2.

At last, the person is allowed to write exam 2 only if he has in both test >= 15 points.

Here's an image of how it currently looks like: http://code2flow.com/Dkf6Vo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand why you need to double checking.
You can use this.

```
 if (test 1 >= 15) {
    certification 1;
    exam 1;
}

if (test 2 >= 15) {
    certification 2;
    if (test 1>=15) {
        exam 1 + 2;
    }
}
```

> When test 1 OK --> exam and certification OK.
>
> When test 2 OK --> certification OK --> Check again whether test 1 also OK --> if OK, give the EXAM
>   if not OK, then don't proceed.

if you want shortest and condition directly on variable.. You can try below

```
exam = test2 >= 15 && test1 >=15 ? 2 : (test1 >= 15 ? 1 : 0) ;

certification = test2 > = 15 ? 2 : (test1 >= 15 ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: You're also "double-checking". I have the condition `if(test 2 >= 15 points)` twice in it, you have the condition `if(test 1 >= 15 points)` twice in it. I've tried to avoid it, but I don't think it's possible. Anyway, your code looks better, since you're not having _certification 2_ twice in it, thanks :)

Comment: btw, what did u mean by "test 1" = it was variable or function?

Comment: test 1 and test 2 are variables (So in real life it'd be a test (like a pre-examination) where the person has to get at least 15 points, so `if(test_1>=15)`). I wrote `test 1 >= 15 points` to make it more clear, sorry if it confused you.

Comment: no problem.. if it was variable, probably you would need this kind of condition - refer my updated answer @Rudi

Comment: I actually just need it to display it as an image so other students understand which test they have to pass to get a certification and write an exam (they don't know any programming language, so I don't want to display the image with variables.. Just for "normal people" to understand it)

Answer (score 1):

In writing code, we should care most about managing complexity, and readability. Reduce one or two if should not be considered as the main criteria. The question should be, how we should design these two logic.

Mixing these certification logic and exam logic is not a sign of a good design.

so, dividing into two different functions a way to improve readability and add flexibility into your program.

```
int getCertificate(int point){
    if(point >= 15)
       return 1;
    return 0;
}

int certificate = getCertificate(exam1) + getCertificate(exam2);

int getExams(int exam1, int exam2){
    if(exam1 >= 15){
       if(exam2 >=15)
          return 2;
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int exam = getExams(exam1, exam2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but my main problem/goal was not how to build a good (structured and actual) code for this solution, but how to use it on this site to get a good and understandable graph/image, which a normal person can understand :)